# my wampserver 2.5. Projects was not opening projects

Tags: server, wamp

I have installed wampserver 2.5 in windows 8. When I click on project in local host is is redirecting to only the project name. Lets take the project name as project1 , when I click on the folder in local host it is directing to project1 it supposed to direct to localhost/project1 something like that.

I have seen some answerers here and changed line 30 in index.php file in www directory. I haven't changed the port at all. And still now it was not opening. It is directing to localhost/project1 but index.php file in project1 was nt displaying. It is saying internal server error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)

Answer (score 0):

if you already changed line 30 in index.php

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

to

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

it should be ok, could you bring what is contents of your project1/index.php ?
also check your /wamp/logs/apache_error.log for details.